# How to determine the time and place of collision of 2 vectors.

Tags: vectors, collision-detection

Object A moves in a straight line, starting at (2,0), After t seconds, its positions (x,y) is given by the equation:

${x \choose y} = {2 \choose 0}+t{0.7 \choose 1}$

Object B travels in a straight line. The equation of its path is:

$\vec r= {1 \choose 35}+p{1 \choose -1}$

where p is the time in minutes.

Object B starts moving 5 minutes after object . Will the 2 collide? If so, when and where?

Yeah I am clueless in how to start this. Equate both of the questions and solve them simultaneously? Can someone please show me how is it done? What are the things i should keep in mind in regard to different takeoff time?

Comment: For your question to make much sense, should the $t$ being used for object $A$'s position not be minutes (like for $B$'s $p$ value) other than seconds? Otherwise, $A$'s $x$ coordinate would be well ahead that of $B$'s initial point after $5$ minutes (also, I assume you meant to say "... after object $A$" instead of not specifying a name), and moving much faster, so it's very clear there's no chance of any collision occurring.

Comment: @JohnOmielan You know, I just copied what it says on the sheet and it says t seconds and p is the time in minutes. And how do you know they are not going to collide?

Comment: After $5$ minutes, i.e., $300$ seconds, object $A$'s $x$ value would be at $2 + 300(0.7) = 212$. Also, every minute, it would be increasing by $60(0.7) = 42$. However, $B$'s $x$ value would start at $1$ and only increase by $1$ every minute. As you can see, $A$'s $x$ value starts off larger and is increasing much faster, so there's no chance it would ever coincide with $B$"s $x$ value at the same time. I believe the sheet has a mistake. If $t$ is in minutes instead, then the question becomes much more reasonable.

Comment: @JohnOmielan okay nice, yeah me too your reasoning seems very valid too me, I will convert t into minutes. Many thanks! Epic Stuff!

Comment: @JohnOmielan hey John! Its me again, i have attempted the problem again using your advice t in minutes, can you check if its right? Let $p=t+5$ and then ${2 \choose 0}+t{0.7 \choose 1} = {1 \choose 35}+(t+5){1 \choose -1}$ However, for the 1st equation i got $t= -13.3$ and $t=15$ for the 2nd equation. Can $t $ become negative?

Comment: I was writing & post an answer instead of just commenting, just before you asked me to answer. You have the right idea, except that since $B$ only starts *after* $A$, then $p$ would be $5$ less than $t$, i.e., $p = t - 5$, not $p = t + 5$ as you state. I hope this makes sense but, if there's anything you don't understand, please let me know. However, it's just $6$ a.m. here where I am. I just woke up for a few minutes & checked the site. Since I'm going back to bed, I won't be responding for at least the next few hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started to answer your question when I noticed some parts don't make much sense. For one thing, you say for $A$ that time $t$ is measured in seconds, but for $B$ it's value of time $p$ is in minutes. Well, after $5$ minutes, i.e., $300$ seconds, object $A$'s $x$ value would be at $2 + 300(0.7) = 212$. Also, every minute, it would be increasing by $60(0.7)=42$. However, $B$'s $x$ value would start at $1$ and only increase by $1$ every minute after that. As you can see, $A$'s $x$ value starts off larger and is increasing much faster, so there's no chance it would ever coincide with $B$'s $x$ value at some later time.

I believe your sheet has a mistake. If $t$ is in minutes instead, then the question becomes much more reasonable. Let us assume this. Then, since $B$ would start $5$ minutes *after* object $A$, this means $p$ would be $5$ *less* than $t$, i.e., $p = t - 5$. Using this, you equate the $x$ and $y$ coordinate equations for objects $A$ and $B$ to solve each for $t$. If they give the same value, then the $2$ objects collide at that time. Otherwise, with different values, it means the $x$ and $y$ coordinates never match at the same time between the $2$ objects and, thus, they never collide.

The equations become

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
2 + 0.7t & = 1 + t - 5 \\
6 & = 0.3t \\
t & = 20
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

and

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
t & = 35 - (t - 5) \\
2t & = 40 \\
t & = 20
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

This means they would collide at a time of $20$ minutes, with a position of $x = 16$ and $y = 20$.

Comment: @Hey John. Thanks for your answer!! This is awesome!!! Sorry for rushing you, my test is around the corner (this friday)!

Answer (score 0):

> Equate both of the questions and solve them simultaneously?

Yes, that's what you do.

The key piece of information is that Object B starts moving $5$ minutes after object A. When $t$ is measured in seconds, this means that $p=t+300$ ($300$ seconds that is, when $t=0$, what is $p$?).

You equate the $x$ and $y$ coefficients:
$$2+0.7t=1 + \frac{t+300}{60}$$
$$t = 35-\frac{t+300}{60}$$

If you have an inconsistent solution (such as when both lines are parallel), then they will never meet and there will be no collision. Otherwise, you can solve for $t$ and substitute back to find $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I believe it's a mistake on the part of the OP (I've commented about it on the question to check with the OP about it), but note the question says that $t$ is in seconds for $A$'s position, but $p$ is in minutes for $B$'s position. Also, note you can solve for $t$ in each of the $2$ equations and, if they match, the positions collide at that time, else they don't at all.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake; it should be $p=t+300$.

Comment: Object $B$ starts moving 5 minutes after object $A$. $t$ is measured in seconds, so when $p$ is $5$ minutes or $300$ seconds, $p = t + 300$ gives $t = 0$ ($0$ seconds).

Comment: @TobyMak Assuming $p$ measures the time in minutes after object $B$ starts moving (the question is not completely clear on this), then with $t$ measured in seconds, you should have $60p = t - 300$ instead. Also, as it is, your equation that $p = t + 300$ implies $p$ and $t$ are measured in the same units.